# For loop ends function prematurely?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, setinterval

I have the following code:

```
var counter = 0;

setInterval(run, 10);

function run() {

    counter++;  

    for (i=0; i<=100; i++) {

        // do something complicated
    }

    alert(counter);
}
```

For some reason, **the alert never gets fired**.

**Does anyone have an idea how this can happen?**

---

By popular demand, the whole code on jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Kriem/ZjPjW/

Comment: The "complicated" thing may contain syntax or other errors.

Comment: Clearly the "do something complicated" is what's breaking it. Perhaps you should post it. Either that or you need to use `setInterval("run()", 100);` (though this may not matter, I've not JS'ed for a while)

Comment: post the whole code on jsFiddle

Comment: @Polynomial: `setInterval(run, 100);` is better than `setInterval("run()", 100)`; you shouldn't pass strings to `setInterval` (or `setTimeout`).

Comment: @Matt - Fair enough. I've not coded in JS for so long I can barely remember any of it!

Comment: See what a difference it makes when you post real code instead of something made up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your for loop is wrong, you have `for(i=0; i<=block.length; i++)` where you should have `for(i=0; i<block.length; i++)`. You are getting an undefined on the last item.

Comment: Om my, this could have taken me all day to find. Thanks so much! These errors are real teeth breakers.

Answer (score 3):

Because on line #188 of your JS Fiddle you're calling `blocks[i].updatePosition(dt);`, and Chrome's console is telling me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'updatePosition' of undefined`

I.e. `blocks[i]` is undefined.

Comment: Hmm, how can it be undefined?

Comment: Yes. Got it. Thanks. Don't know about the downvotes, but thanks for the help.

Comment: @Kriem It's undefined because `blocks.length` returns the index of the last array item + 1. And since your `for` loop runs even when `i` is equal to the length, it checks for the item in the array that is at the last item's index + 1.

Answer (score -2):

My first guess would be that the function doesn't get called.

Comment: ah :)
Does the alert get executed when you comment out the for loop?